# Uploadify 2.1.4 does not work with Firefox 23

Tags: firefox, uploadify

Uploadify 2.1.4 has stopped working Firefox (tested on 22 and 23).  It still works with Chrome and Opera.

In Firefox, I click the upload button and nothing happens.

Is there a fix to this?

The Uploadify 3 demo page works in Firefox. So if I cannot get a fix, I'll try upgrading. 
I'm using JQuery 1.7.2

Unfortunately I cannot share an example as you need a user account to our website to use it.

Comment: I decided to switch to the Jquery File Upload library.  This worked and it also removed my project's dependency on Flash.